# android acitivity without registering in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I came across a problem in a job interview that whether I can dynamically add a new activity to an Android application without releasing a new version of the app. And he told me that there exists certain mechanism that we could dynamically change the Activity to a new one, without registering in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I searched some documents, but did not found possible way to do this.

Can I start an Activity without registering in the AndroidManifest.xml file? And is it possible to dynamically modify the existing Activity?

Comment: For `dynamically change the activity`, I believe he meant fragment. You can choose to have only one activity through out the whole application, all you do is switch its containing fragments. Which, if this is the case, your interviewee might not be able to differentiate between fragment and activity, or he is testing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Can I start an Activity without registering in the AndroidManifest.xml file?`

No. I don't think you can start an activity that is not registered in the AndroidManifest.xml file. The manifest file keeps track of the activities that the app can use upon compiling/building the application. Any attempt to open an unregistered activity will result in an application crash.

`And is it possible to dynamically modify the existing Activity?`

As Bette Devine said, you can change the layout of the existing activity by calling `setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);` based on some user action (like a button press). However, calling `setContentView` more than once in your activity is a bad practice that people generally avoid doing. It is not recommended since you'll have to write code that would manage user interaction for the second layout. Imagine writing two activity codes in one java file. That would result in unnecessary clutter of code when you can just write them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to dynamically modify an existing one. 
Here modification does not mean that you are changing the name of an activity but means that you are changing the content.

Just call the setContentView method of activity to give a new layout to the activiy and you whole activity now will be hosting a different content.

```
setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
```